# Force user input to yes when installing package in recipe

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm new to Chef and I'm trying to install '**java-1_7_0-openjdk**' through the package resource as follow:

```
package 'java-1_7_0-openjdk' do
    action [:install]
end
```

When running this is kitchen, however, it fails due to '*no user input*' on the confirmation prompt '**do you want to install packages (y/n)**'

I can't figure out how to **--force-install** or **-y** to skip the confirmation step.
I've tried configuring my kitchen.yml to automatically accept installs but no luck there either.
I'm trying to install this package on a Linux suse kitchen environment.

My kitchen.yml:

```
---
 28 driver:
 27   name: vagrant
 26
 25 provisioner:
 24   name: chef_zero
 23   # You may wish to disable always updating cookbooks in CI or other testing environments.
 22   # For example:
 21   #   always_update_cookbooks: <ommited>
 20   # always_update_cookbooks: true
 19   # http_proxy: 'http_proxy'
 18   # https_proxy: 'http_proxy'
 17   product_name: chef
 16   product_version: latest
 15   install_strategy: always
 14   environments_path: test/environments
 13   data_bags_path: "test/fixtures/data_bags"
 12   roles_path: "test/fixtures/roles"
 10   client_rb:
  9     environment: kitchen
  8     rubygems_url: 'ommited'
  7     #chef_license: accept    <<<<----- tried this, does not fix the problem
  6     install_strategy: always <<<<----- tried this, does not fix the problem
  5 verifier:
  4   name: inspec
  3   inspec_tests:
  2     - path: test/integration/default
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction? I'm at a total loss as to where to go from here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use existing cookbooks if available for services installation and configuration.
For example for **java** I used the following one:
https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/java

Just add the following line on **metadata.rb**:

```
depends 'java','1.39.0'
```

And then on your cookbook recipe:

```
node.default['java']['ark_timeout'] = 6000
node.default['java']['install_flavor'] = "oracle"
node.default['java']['oracle']['accept_oracle_download_terms'] = true
node.default['java']['jdk_version'] = 8
include_recipe 'java'
```

The **java.oracle.accept_oracle_download_terms** attribute set to **true** for this cookbook solve the problem to accept terms as in your scenario